# MySQL query sum in Left Join

Tags: mysql

The query below is using SUM in the select and joining two tables.  The results for the SUM are including amounts from all periods.  I suspect that is due to where the SUM is placed.
I think the post [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/175786/join-multiple-tables-for-aggregates)
contains the same issue I am having.  I have tried to follow the solution given but cannot seem to get it to work.

Query:

```
SELECT
  Mo911ZipLookup.X_STATE AS StateAbbr,
  Mo911ZipLookup.X_CITY AS City,
  Mo911ZipLookup.X_COUNTY AS County,
  SUM(SourceDataTCX.E911Amount) AS E911Amount,
  SourceDataTCX.period AS period
FROM (SourceDataTCX
  LEFT JOIN Mo911ZipLookup
    ON ((SourceDataTCX.ZipCode = Mo911ZipLookup.X_ZIPCODE)))
WHERE (Mo911ZipLookup.X_STATE = 'MO' AND SourceDataTCX.period = '2019-02-01')
GROUP BY Mo911ZipLookup.X_STATE,
         Mo911ZipLookup.X_CITY,
         Mo911ZipLookup.X_COUNTY,
         SourceDataTCX.period
ORDER BY Mo911ZipLookup.X_STATE, Mo911ZipLookup.X_COUNTY, Mo911ZipLookup.X_CITY
```

The query should return amounts for just the 2019-02-01 period but it includes amounts from all periods.  I think the SUM should be moved into the join.  Can someone help me with that?

*Edit*
The query produces results like:

```
StateAbbr   City    County  E911Amount  period  
MO  BALLWIN SAINT LOUIS 614.80  2019-02-01
MO  ELLISVILLE  SAINT LOUIS 614.80  2019-02-01
MO  MANCHESTER  SAINT LOUIS 614.80  2019-02-01
MO  TWIN OAKS   SAINT LOUIS 614.80  2019-02-01
MO  WILDWOOD    SAINT LOUIS 614.80  2019-02-01
MO  WINCHESTER  SAINT LOUIS 614.80  2019-02-01
```

The amount for each city total showing as the total for all cities.  I think the SUM is being applied before the GROUP BY.

Answer (score 0):

Move the filter `Mo911ZipLookup.X_STATE = 'MO'` to the `ON` clause:

```
 SELECT Mo911ZipLookup.X_STATE AS StateAbbr,
   Mo911ZipLookup.X_CITY AS City,
   Mo911ZipLookup.X_COUNTY AS `County,,
   z.E911Amount,
   z.period AS period FROM
(
 SELECT SUM(E911Amount`) AS E911Amount,period AS period, ZipCode
 FROM SourceDataTCX
 WHERE period = '2019-02-01'
GROUP BY period, ZipCode      
) z
LEFT JOIN Mo911ZipLookup ON  z.ZipCode = Mo911ZipLookup.X_ZIPCODE
                      AND Mo911ZipLookup.X_STATE = 'MO' 
ORDER BY Mo911ZipLookup.X_STATE, Mo911ZipLookup.X_COUNTY, Mo911ZipLookup.X_CITY
```

Comment: Thanks but that did not work.  I think the problem is that the SUM is being calculated before the GROUP BY.

Comment: if it's a 1 to many relationship between the 2 tables then the SourceDataTCX.E911Amount will get duplicated, you would need to sum it in a subquery. Let me know if this is the issue.

Comment: Yes, I think that may be it.  Mo911ZipLookup.X_ZIPCODE is not always a 1 to 1 match.

Comment: I changed the query in my answer. You can give it a try.